Como generar entidades html en react
Me hice el siguiente componente
const pintaEspacios = (spaces: number) => {
  return (<>{'&nbsp;'.repeat(spaces)}</>);
}

El problema es que me está imprimiendo como cadena los &nbsp;, y solamente quisiera que generara las entidades HTML.
¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50187789/5843452
